# Local Notifications on Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Good day,
I need to build local notifications on my xamarin.forms, so i started from android:
1. In the `core` project i've created an interface:

```
 public interface INotification
    {
        void CreateNotification();
    }
```

2. In the `Droid` i've implemented notifications:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(Notification))]
namespace Test.Droid
{

    class Notification : Interfaces.INotification
    {
        public void CreateNotification()
        {
            string content = @"Here is the text";
            int messageId = 999;

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Application.Context)
                .SetAutoCancel(true)
                .SetContentTitle("My Notifications")
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
                .SetContentText("Click here to next Activity")
                .SetStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().BigText(content))
                ;

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
            notificationManager.Notify(messageId, builder.Build());


        }
    }
}
```

3. Finally, I put a dependency service on the main page of the core project

   ```
   public MainPage()
           {
               InitializeComponent();
               DependencyService.Get<INotification>().CreateNotification();
   ```

   }

But i dont see a notification!
P.S. Its working fine on xamarin.android app.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was in a worng dependency :

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(Test.Droid.Notification))]
```

**SOLVED**